# Error en produccion de importaciones dinamicas

Tags: laravel, reactjs, webpack

Buenas tengo una aplicacion desarrollada en react,usando la carga diferida (lazy loading) .La cuestion es que al ejecutar el comando npm run watch si se ejecuta como estaba planeado y me genera los archivos correspondientes,pero cuando lo quiero mandar a produccion me lanza este error.

```
CssSyntaxError: /css/app.css:3:13: Missed semicolon
```

pensé que mi css estaba mal , pero cuando borro las lineas de las importaciones vuelve a funcionar.Alguna solución?(estoy utilizando el mix de laravel).
Package.json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

webpack.mix.js

```
    mix.options({
   terser: {
      terserOptions: {
         compress: true
      }
   }
});
mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Pon tu codigo que se encuentra en `css/app.css`

Comment: no lo añadiré como respuesta pero me paso lo mismo con vue. El problema se debe a que no esta bien configurado el soporte para los archivos asíncronos. La solución que yo encontré fue hacer la compilación de los css por separado. Primero compilo los js y después los css.